# Design suggestions for an Image class hierarchy

Tags: c++, oop

I need some design suggestions for an Image class hierarchy.
Currently, I have 2 types of images (one is a standard image, the second doesn't contain standard image data).
Sometimes I want the object to allocate the memory for the image data, and other times I just want it to point to it.

The problem arises when I want to give TypeA images specific functionality.
If TypeA images inherit from Image, I will have to duplicate the functionality of the Allocated vs. non-Allocated Image.

I'm sure there is a better way to do this, I remember some elegant solutions with mixins during university, but can't find a way to use that here.

My current design looks like:

```
class Image
{
public:
Image(int width, int height, int bpp);
virtual ~Image() {};
    // getters

    template <typename T>                                  
    T* ptr() { return reinterpret_cast<T*>(m_imageData); } // T depends on bpp

 protected:
    // metadata
    char* m_imageData;
};

class AllocImage : public Image
{
public:
    AllocImage(int width, int height, int bpp, DataType dataType) :
        Image(width, height, bpp, dataType)
    {
        m_imageData = new char[m_dataSize];
    }

    ~AllocImage()
    {
        delete m_imageData;
    }
};

class ImageHolder : public Image
{
public:
    ImageHolder(int width, int height, int bpp, DataType m_dataType);

    void setPtr(const void* ptr);
};

class AllocatedImageTypeA : public AllocImage
{
public:
    // Type A specific methods
};

class NonAllocatedImageTypeA : public ImageHolder
{
public:
    // duplicated Type A specific methods
};
```

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html should be a starting point. I'd rather have allocators as a template parameter with a default allocator. Also, is `ImageHolder` a lightweight image access class?

Comment: @dirkgently `ImageHolder` gives you all the behaviour of Image, but does not allocate any memory, just points to where the image data is located.

Comment: So, this is a lightweight accessor object. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/gil/doc/html/gildesignguide.html#ImageViewSectionDG. The Flyweight pattern comes to mind. Also, specifics of access/mutation characteristics may be helpful to us!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the differences are constrained to how the image is held (allocated or not), you could use the [policy model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design).

The short explanation is that you would pass a policy object to the image, where the policy describes whether you need to deallocate the image or not, how to access it, etc., basically anything that relates to the differences that arise from how the image data is held (allocated vs. pointed).  Then all your access to the image will be through the policy.

For example, instead of writing

```
delete image;
```

You would write:

```
policy.del(image);
```

Where `policy.del` can be a delegate to `delete` or a no-op, depending on the actual type of the policy (that is in line with what the image requires)

Comment: TypeA and TypeB images types have extended functionality on the basic Image. Either of them can be allocated or not. So I want to share the functionality of allocated or not between both, but want to give each their specific behaviour

Comment: So you design your class hierarchy based on TypeA and TypeB, and pass the proper policy object/type based on whether the image is allocated or not

Comment: I will try this, I've read about policies in Alexandrescu's book but haven't tried using them yet.

Comment: It does not have to be a template if that's too troublesome for you to understand, you can do the same with actual policy objects (e.g passed in via the constructor)

Answer (score 0):

Why so many types?  If the difference is only in allocation, then simply create multiple constructors, one which takes a pointer to a pre-allocated data holder, one that doesn't and does the allocation internally.  You could also use [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to get the variations in behaviour / functionality.

Comment: The `ImageHolder` does not take a pre-allocated pointer, it receives the pointer dynamically from `HW` and thus needs some sort of `setPtr` method. I don't want to have a `setPtr` method in an internally allocated image.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case.

Let's make something clear. Your class hierarchy its not based if an image is allocated or not, but, each class will have some features.

You may want to have a very specialized class that allocates images, another that references, and, warp that class with another of the same hierarchy, with similar features.

The following example, explains the idea of wraping one class, with another class,
from the same inheritance, that seems to apply to your questio.

Disclaimer: Please ignore, some minor bugs or non relevant syntax errors:

```
// generic base class for my image library:
/* abstract */ class GenericImage
{
public:
   int width;
   int height;

public:
    /* constructor */ GenericImage() ;
    /* destructor */ ~GenericImage() ;

    /* constructor */ GenericImage(int newwidth, int newheight);
}; // class GenericImage

// in charge of allocating or deallocating an image
class AllocatedImage: GenericImage
{
public:
    /* constructor */ AllocatedImage() ;
    /* destructor */ ~AllocatedImage() ;

    /* constructor */ AllocatedImage(int newwidth, int newheight);
    /* constructor */ AllocatedImage(char* filename);
}; // class AllocatedImage

// access an image, but doesn't allocate or deallocate
class ContainedImage: GenericImage
{
public:
    /* constructor */ ContainedImage() ;
    /* destructor */ ~ContainedImage() ;

    /* constructor */ ContainedImage(int newwidth, int newheight);
}; // class AllocatedImage

// real working class, will allocate other objects,
// of same hierarchy
class WrapperImage: GenericImage
{
public:
   GenericImage* RealImage;

public:
    /* constructor */ GenericImage() ;
    /* destructor */ ~GenericImage() ;

   void AllocateImage(AllocatedImage* newimage);
   void HoldImage(ContainedImage* newimage);
}; // class AllocatedImage
```

Suggestions:

1. Its good idea, to have a constructor without parameters, specially if you are designing a class hierarchy, instead of a single class.
2. I know its a quick example, but, you may want to move all code to body file.

Cheers.